# Using symfony LoginFormAuthenticator with lexik_jwt_authentication to handle admin user and api token

Tags: symfony, authentication, forms-authentication, api-platform.com

I want to create an admin user to handle back-end and to use jwt token to protect my API routes.

In my security.yaml file i add a main firewall to handle login form authentication :

```
 main:
            anonymous: lazy
            provider: app_user_provider
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout
```

and i config access control :

```
- { path: '^/admin', roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
- { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Now, if i use login form, i can sign in as an admin :

[image: sign in]

[image: admin controller]

After sign in i can access to the admin controller.

I added jwt lexik bundle and i added config to security.yaml :

```
login:
            pattern:  ^/api/login
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            json_login:
                check_path:               /api/login_check
                success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
        api:
            pattern:   ^/api
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
```

And i added config to api_platform.yaml:

```
api_platform:
    mapping:
        paths: ['%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity']
    patch_formats:
        json: ['application/merge-patch+json']
    swagger:
        versions: [3]
        api_keys:
            apiKey:
                name: Authorization
                type: header
    title: API partage de mandats
    version: 1.0.0
    collection:
        pagination:
            client_enabled: true
            enabled_parameter_name: pagination # optional
    eager_loading:
        enabled: false
```

I want to make public access to my api, and prevent testing api without token :

My api look like this :
[image: api]

The problem is : i can got ressource event if i'm not authenticated :

[image]

My current acces control is :

[image]

How can i add config to security.yaml to prevent public access to api ressources ?

Answer (score -1):

Could, you just add this line to your access_control:

```
security:
    # ...
    access_control:
        - { path: '^/api/mandates', roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: '^/api', roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Comment: if i add ROLE_USER  to api, that means user should be authenticated to see the documentation. i want that ^/api be public, but  ^/api/mandates is protected.

Answer (score -1):

I fix the problem.
All i need to do is to add a slash to my route in the firewall :

```
api:
            pattern:   ^/api/
            stateless: true
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
```

Now everything work like i want .